# Why is this trigonometry code written this way?

Tags: c#, optimization, trigonometry

I'm reading some code that someone else wrote in C#, and I've come across a function similar to the following:

```
public double calculate(double radianAngle)
{
    double sine = Math.Sin(radianAngle);
    double cosine;
    if(angle > 0.0 && angle < Math.PI / 2.0)
        cosine = Math.Sqrt(1.0 - sine * sine);
    else
        cosine = Math.Cos(radianAngle);

    // ... unrelated code here

    return resultThatUsesSineAndCosine;
}
```

What this code seems to be referring to is the math identity:

```
(cos(x))^2 = 1 - (sin(x))^2
```

But why would you need to add an if statement for this? And why do it in the first place if it's just going to be equal to `Math.Cos(radianAngle)`? Is there a reason such as better accuracy? Or is this micro-optimization? Or could it be that this code was micro-optimized in another language (C++) then ported to C# with the micro-optimization intact? And even if was micro-optimization, why would it only work for angles between 0 and pi/2?

Comment: I would say that you are right and it is just a microoptimization from somewhere else. and in terms of [0..90] - both sin and cos > 0 on that range

Comment: Interesting related info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683588/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-compute-sin-and-cos-together